# What is this SQL attempting to do? SELECT 202001%100

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I've come across the below in a SELECT statement in SQL Server 2016 db and have never seen the use of a percent sign like this before:

```
SELECT 202001%100
```

I get a result of 1 for this

Tried searching everywhere but can't seem to find out the usage of % in the above example.

Can anyone help please?

Comment: What kind of database is this?

Comment: SQL Server 2016

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `%` symbol is the [modulus operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/modulo-transact-sql). It gives you the **remainder** of a division operation. Since `202001` divided by `100` is `2020` with a remainder of `1`, then `202001` modulus `100` is `1`.

In this case, it looks like someone made the ***extremely poor choice*** to handle year/month values as integers, and is using modulus to find the month (January). That seems to work for simple things, but it discards the ability to use the more advanced date/time functions, as well as leaving you vulnerable to a number of tricky edge cases that are solved when using real date values.

Instead, it's almost always better to use one of the formal DateTime types with the first day of the month in the day position, even if you don't care about the day.

Comment: That is the modulo operator - the return value is the modulus.

Comment: It does not have to be year-month, it could be anything like year-quarter/year-week number

Comment: @LukaszSzozda True. But it doesn't change the prescription: you're almost always better off using one of the formal datetime types with the first day of each period.

Comment: I tend to use the last day in the month, so that `EOMONTH` works nicely, unfortunately there is no `SOMONTH` function

Comment: @Charlieface That's because the first day is always a numeric 1.

Comment: I mean it makes my life easier otherwise I have to constantly write stupid `datetimefromparts` functions. I only use it in `group by`s. Just need to remember that it's **the beginning** of the ast day of month.

Comment: Or `DATEADD(day, 1, EOMONTH([date], -1))`